# Chrome in the launcher does not open with keyboard hotkey (Super + #)

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, launcher, google-chrome

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I have chrome as the first application locked in my launcher. When I click it or press `Super+1` the Chrome icon just flashes, but never opens the app. All other apps open fine. I have to manually find it in Unity and launch it from there, or from Terminal. I've set this to launch properly on another machine but I don't know why it's not working on my laptop.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Well, I've since reinstalled Ubuntu due to other reasons, and I myself haven't been able to reproduce this issue. It now works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try unlocking it from unity launcher and locking it again? or moving it another place to check if there is a problem with the "super +1" key shortcut and not the program? also try to hold the "super" key on hold to check if the 1 number appears on top of the app.

Comment: I've tried all of that and it still doesn't work. For some strange reason though, my work computer (also running 14.04) does this without problems.